# What is the error I am making when I'm installing the passport dependencies?

Tags: laravel

```
Using version ^10.1 for laravel/passport
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update laravel/passport
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - laravel/passport[v10.1.0, ..., 10.x-dev] require illuminate/auth ^8.2 -> found illuminate/auth[v8.2.0, ..., 8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/passport ^10.1 -> satisfiable by laravel/passport[v10.1.0, v10.1.1, v10.1.2, 10.x-dev].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

Comment: What version of laravel/framework are you using?

Answer (score 0):

you must check your project dependencies and laravel dependencies , you can test this remove composer.lock file and run this `composer install`

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade your Laravel or install an older version of Laravel Passport

composer require laravel/passport:X.x.x